# Converting Unityscript to c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript

Can anyone help me convert this Unityscript code to C# in Unity3d. I am having trouble understanding variable text and transform (i.e var text: Transform;)

```
#pragma strict


var text: Transform;
```

Comment: it's unityscript, not javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code you've posted thus far, the C# equivalent would be:

```
Transform text;
```

`Transform` is the type. `text` is the name of the variable being declared.

Unity actually provides a beginner video that explains the syntax differences between JS and C#:

[Unity - C# vs JS syntax](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/c-sharp-vs-javascript-syntax)